# Overloading with similar conversions

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading, visual-studio

Given these two functions :

```
bool logMessage(LogType_E, unsigned int, int, const char *, ...); //!< Log message with parameters

bool logMessage(LogType_E, int, const char *, ...); //!< Logs message with domain of Log class
```

And calling one of them :

```
A3D_LOG_INSTANCE.logMessage(Log::LOG_INFO, 0, "Number = %d", 10);
```

> Error 1   error C2666: 'AX::Base::Log::logMessage' : 2 overloads have
>   similar
>   conversions   o:\AX_FusRecAlg\src\base\test.u\LogSimpleFileTest\LogSimpleFileTest.cpp 50  AX.Base.LogSimpleFileTest

Could someone explain to me in plain English why this error occurs and possibly offer an alternative? I don't understand how the function which has 3 arguments before the char* matches with the function which has two arguments?!

Thanks.

**Edit :**

Since some of you are wondering that I am hiding information : 
**The function signature cannot be changed. No templates can be used.** Just an explanation of why this error occurs would suffice.

```
enum LogType_E {
        LOG_ERROR       = 0,            //!< error
        LOG_WARNING     = 1,            //!< warning
        LOG_SUCCESS     = 2,            //!< success
        LOG_INFO        = 3,            //!< info
        LOG_TRACE       = 4,            //!< trace message if tracing is enabled
        LOG_TRACE1      = 5,            //!< trace level 1
        LOG_TRACE2      = 6,            //!< trace level 2
        LOG_TRACE3      = 7,            //!< trace level 3
        LOG_TRACE4      = 8             //!< trace level 4
    };


bool logMessage(LogType_E, unsigned int, int, const char *, ...)
{
    return true;
}

bool logMessage(LogType_E, int, const char *, ...)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    logMessage(LOG_TRACE, 0, 0, "Teststring 2");
    return 0;
}
```

Copy and paste above code into a .cpp file and run it or [click](http://ideone.com/FAb2B) here.

Comment: what version of the compiler are you using? This seems like a splendid case for variadic templates

Comment: @sehe I would love to use that but I can't. Compiler is MSVS 2008. Oh and on top of that template usage in this .dll is forbidden.

Comment: Not sure how to solve this but this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyafzty4(v=vs.80).aspx) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Carl thanks but I did search google and SO before posting my question.

Comment: Given those two functions, the compiler should unambiguously call the second, since the first can't be called; neither the third nor the fourth arguments can be converted to the target type.  So there's something you're not telling us.

Comment: There is a lot you're not telling us. We're in the business of helping people solve programming problems, not creating overconstrained programming puzzles (oh - and the constraints aren't even mentioned in the post). We have **[Pex4Fun](http://pex4fun.com/)** for that

Comment: @sehe I don't understand what I am not telling you? I just posted a minimal reproducible sample which has exactly the same error. I just would like to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @FailedDev: just read your own comments. All that info was missing from the post. Personally, I think that is demotivating. Moreover, it is not helping _you_ get an answer, so I think you should care.

Comment: @FailedDev The arguments in the edited example aren't the same as in the original question.  In the edited example, both functions can be called; for the second argument, `0`, the `int` in the second is the better match, where as for the third, the `char const*` in the first is a better match.  So ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. From your example:

```
logMessage(LOG_TRACE, 0, 0, "Teststring 2");
```

Second parameter can be both, `int` and `unsigned int`.
You will have to make explicit cast to make it work.

For example:

```
logMessage(LOG_TRACE, (unsigned int)0, 0, "Teststring 2");
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, then, let me suggest the shorthand approach: `logMessage(LOG_TRACE, 0u, 0, "Teststring 2");` (see it live: http://ideone.com/LlCPh)